# Excel ( how to produce multiplication with decimal values )

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to calculate to show the decimal places but I cant seem to find it . After rounding off the value seems to be always 178.00

Formula 
A = Amount / 1.12

Ex.200 / 1.12 = 178.57

Comment: and what do you expect to see ? 178.57143... ?

Comment: What is the exact formula you are using to produce the 178.00 result? And what cell formatting? Your use of the expression "after rounding off" suggests that you are using something like `INT()` in your formula.

Comment: Please explain your question more clearly. What are you doing, what result are you getting, and what result do you want? Why does your question title talk about multiplication when your question seems to be about division?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To produce just the decimal portion of the answer to 200 / 1.12 you would need to use the formula

```
=(200/1.12)-INT(200/1.12)
```

Therefore if, let's say, `Amount` was in cell `A1`, and you want to calculate `Amount / 1.12`, the formula to use would be

```
=(A1/1.12)-INT(A1/1.12)
```

You just need to substitute `A1` with whatever cell `Amount` is in.

Comment: ```=MOD(A1/1.12, 1)``` is equivalent but more concise.

Comment: @G-Man but does have some limitations with large numbers.

Comment: Thank you , sorry if I wasn't clear with my question , what I want was to divine but getting the decimal also . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had Google Sheets set to use `,` as the [decimal separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator) instead of `.`. So I just did

```
=A2*1,12
```

and it worked. Then I went to File -> Settings and changed my region to United States.

Answer (score 0):

The `PRODUCT` function is used to do multiplication in Excel, for all decimal and integer values.

```
=PRODUCT(A2,B2)
```

Apply this to get the result.

Comment: This question is very unclear, so I might be missing the point — but I doubt that this is what the asker is looking for.